# gradle - "compileJava" not compiling Java because "UP-TO-DATE"?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gradle

Let's say I have a simple class

```
public class A {
    public int inc(int k, int i){
        System.out.println(i);
        return 0;
    }
}
```

And I call it from `Main`

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new A().inc(0,7);
    }
}
```

The corresponding java bytecode (`javap -c A.class`):

```
public class A {
  public A();
    Code:
       0: aload_0
       1: invokespecial #1                  // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
       4: return

  public int inc(int, int);
    Code:
       0: getstatic     #2                  // Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
       3: iload_2
       4: invokevirtual #3                  // Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(I)V
       7: iconst_0
       8: ireturn
}
```

Note the `iload_2`.

Now let's remove the unnecessary parameter `k`.

```
public class A {
    public int inc(int i){
        System.out.println(i);
        return 0;
    }
}
```

and of course

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new A().inc(7);
    }
}
```

Now if I re-run the code, A will be compiled to

```
public class A {
  public A();
    Code:
       0: aload_0
       1: invokespecial #1                  // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
       4: return

  public int inc(int);
    Code:
       0: getstatic     #2                  // Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
       3: iload_1
       4: invokevirtual #3                  // Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(I)V
       7: iconst_0
       8: ireturn
}
```

Which is what I'd expect.
However, let's say I don't want to re-run everything and am just interested in the bytecode-level changes ...

```
gradle compileJava
```

and then

```
javap -c A.class
```

it will not have changed.

And in fact, upon checking gradle output, there's a

```
:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
```

There that clearly doesn't belong there.

Now, I've created the project with the Intellij (2017.2.4) wizard, (gradle project with Java as "additional libraries and frameworks", using SDK1.8), added the `Main` and `A` classes, and tested this.

What do I need to change to make this work the way it's supposed to?

Comment: Are you saying that you change a `.java` file and gradle thinks it's `UP-TO-DATE`? This is pretty battle tested stuff, I'd be very surprised if gradle behaved like this unless you did something silly like `upToDateWhen { true }` or the file is not in `src/main/java`. Or maybe it's a multi-project build and a different project is being reported as `UP-TO-DATE`?

Comment: @lance-java I've done literally nothing that I haven't mentioned in my post, that's why I'm confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so it's not an issue with Gradle, but rather a misconfiguration of Intelij's.

When creating the project,

Gradle will compile to `.\build\classes`,

but the "module compile output path" in project structure -> modules is set to `.\out\production\classes` - which is from where Intellij will take the bytecode and run the classes.

It's also where recompiling Gradle doesn't touch any files.

I've opened [a different question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46420541/intellij-set-default-output-path-to-gradle-output) on how to deal with that, as this answers this question.